# Not able to upload/get the AWS bucket files in gov-cloud account

Tags: amazon-s3

I'm able to access the s3 files in the normal AWS account but while migrating to gov-cloud the same code throws following errors for upload/get the contents of the bucket

```
InvalidAccessKeyId: The AWS Access Key Id you provided does not exist in our records.
```

and

```
code: 'Forbidden',
region: null,
time: 2022-01-31T16:13:56.658Z,
requestId: 'VJEF4741265DQNA3DF',
extendedRequestId: 'i6cztQJ5u/u9u0a0UZS412365789yshyGmplnn4Ph4qhabm52145f8i8sCITROMYx52Y65oAKE=',
cfId: undefined,
statusCode: 403,
retryable: false,
retryDelay: 53.65986294598015
```

All the keys and policies are configured but no idea where's it getting failed

Here is the code snippet:

```js
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const fs = require('fs');

const s3 = new AWS.S3({
  accessKeyId: 'ACCESS_KEY',
  secretAccessKey: 'SECRET_KEY',
});
const fileName="Capture.png"
const fileContent = fs.readFileSync(fileName);

const params = {
  Bucket: 'upload', // pass your bucket name
  Key: `test.jpg`, 
  Body: fileContent,
  ACL: 'public-read',
};
s3.headObject(
  {
    Bucket: 'upload',
    Key: `KEY`,
  },
  (err, data) => {
    if(err){
      console.log(err)
    }
    else{
      console.log("data",data)
    }
  })
s3.upload(params, function(err, data) {
  if (err) {
    throw err;
  }
  console.log(`File uploaded successfully. ${data.Location}`);
});
```

Please suggest any solution for the above error if have any.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1):

Had similar issue with GovCloud S3 when using aws cli (not SDK) but I assume it's the same.
For me adding `region` parameter (with relevant value `us-gov-west-1` / `us-gov-east-1` )to command, which wasn't necessary in other AWS regions, solved it.
try adding `region` to your `new AWS.S3()` config

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/govcloud-us/latest/UserGuide/cli-and-api-access.html

Answer (score 0):

From https://docs.aws.amazon.com/govcloud-us/latest/UserGuide/govcloud-iam.html

> IAM users that you create in AWS GovCloud (US) are specific to AWS GovCloud (US) and do not exist in other standard AWS Regions.

So if you have created an access key id and secret access key outside GovCloud, it won't work inside GovCloud.

If creating a new IAM access key in GovCloud does not work, use the steps given in the following link to debug your issue:

https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/s3-access-key-error/

A short summary of the steps in the above link:

1. Configure AWS CLI to use your secret access key and then run the command `aws sts get-caller-identity` to confirm that your credentials work.
2. Verify that your IAM user and associated secret access key exists.